# SQL - adding values to table fields if some fields are filled and other fields need to be filled

Tags: mysql, database

I have created a table (name) with these fields: person_id, first_name, last_name.

The `person_id` field already holds values like 1, 2, 3. Now i want to add values to the remaining fields i.e first_name. How do I add different values to different fields if one field is already filled and another needs to have some data inserted with SQL, using a single statement?

This is my table :

```
name
================================
person_id  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ...
first_name |   |   |   |   | 
last_name  |   |   |   |   |
```

Comment: Please look you table structure friend, have you transformed Columns into rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an UPDATE query, for example:

```
UPDATE
  name
SET
  first_name = 'John',
  last_name = 'Smith'
WHERE
  person_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If field already has value, it will not updated else it will.

```
UPDATE
  name
SET
  first_name = Case When first_name is null then 'John' else first_name end,
  last_name =  Case When last_name is null then 'Smith' else last_name end
WHERE
  person_id = 1
```